# In mongodb, how to add field from one collection document to another collection document based on criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am having 2 collections -

1. Collection name is **content**

[image]

2. Collection name is **surveys**

[image]

I actually want to add the "type" information from the content collection to every content in every survey in the "surveys" collection.

I know in SQL we have to join these 2 tables first on _id and content_id commun columns and then add type column to suryeys table but not sure how should i do it here. I want the type value from content collection to add in every content field inside surveys collection. Please help me.

Comment: Use an aggregation pipeline that starts with `$lookup` step and ends in a '$merge` step

Comment: @nimrodserok  i tried something like this but its not working {
    $lookup: {
        from: "content",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "content_id",
        as: "someField"
    }
},
{
    $addFields: {
      newField  : "$someField.type"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$newField"
},
{
    $project: {
        someField: 0
    }
}

Comment: You are missing a `$merge` step in the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is:

1. Using `$lookup` to get the data from `content` collection
2. Merge the arrays using `$mergeObjects` and `$indexOfArray`. After the lookup, the `content` data is on `someField` array. This step finds the releant `content` from `someField` and put it inside the matching survey's content item, under the key `type`. This step also removes `someField`.
3. Format the result using `$map`. This step uses `$map` to iterate over the `content` array and format the data under `type` to contain only the wanted part.
4. Save it back using `$merge`. This step saves the result back into the collection.

```
db.surey.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "content",
      localField: "content.content_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "someField"
  }},
  {$set: {
      someField: "$$REMOVE",
      content: {$map: {
          input: "$content",
          in: {$mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {type: {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    "$someField",
                    {$indexOfArray: ["$someField._id", "$$this.content_id"]}
                  ]
              }}
          ]}
      }}
  }},
  {$set: {content: {$map: {
          input: "$content",
          in: {$mergeObjects: ["$$this", {type: "$$this.type.type"}]}
  }}}},
  {$merge: {into: "surey"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pGG-z-28kHx)

Comment: Wow.. thank you so much @nimrod-serok . Could you please explain me how you have built this query since it is very hard for me to understand.

Comment: After lookup, i am not able to understand anything... could you please explain briefly what all each step is doing after lookup since i am very new to mongodb

Comment: just now noticed that this is giving me an error in Mongosh which i am running inside .MongoDBCompass This is the error- "clone(t={}){const r=t.loc||{};return e({loc:new Position("line"in r?r.line:this.loc.line,"column"in r?r.column:...<omitted>...)} could not be cloned."
    at Object.serialize (node:v8:332:7)

Comment: Updated the answer with some more explanation. I'm not familiar with this error. Please try to reproduce it on the mongodb playground and share it

Answer (score 0):

In mongoose (I assume you could be using mongoose, sind you added the tag) you can specify the relation in Schema definition and just just populate to add these fields to the output.

If you are not using mongoose you can use $lookup (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in your aggregation pipeline.

```
{ 
  from: "content", 
  localField: "content._id", 
  foreignField: "_id", 
  as: "someField" 
}
```

Comment: I tried something like this but it's not working {
    $lookup: {
        from: "content",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "content_id",
        as: "someField"
    }
},
{
    $addFields: {
      newField  : "$someField.type"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$newField"
},
{
    $project: {
        someField: 0
    }
}

Comment: I took your query and adjusted my comment. „localField“ is referring to the field of the collection you are aggregating on. Therefore the fields had to be switched.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but could you please write the entire query which you think will work here. I would really appreciate your help